# Free alternatives to jqGrid for ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

Trirand makes a fantastic [server-side jQuery grid component](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx). It's bindable in code-behind, but acts like the jQuery-only grid.

Are there any free competitors or alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/).

Comment: You can use my library for integration with ASP.NET /IQueryable https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables

Answer (score 0):

If you're not set on jQuery, there's [Ext.NET](http://www.ext.net/) which is a server-side implementation of ExtJS.